# Spring boot and tomcat policies - access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to do a deployment of a spring-boot application to a tomcat.
Unfortunately, we do not control the tomcat.

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
```

And I see that the spring-boot framework does try to use reflection and check the various classes and factories inside:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4a883d00a5a6842e53086207c259fd053be1ce43/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L440

```
29-Nov-2018 18:46:34.152 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-Nov-2018 18:46:34.596 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mne-api]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:143)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:448)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:427)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:418)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.createSpringApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:90)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createSpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:128)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:168)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:444)
```

### Questions

1. Is it something I have done, or is it clearly a problem with the configuration of the server?
2. Could the error be something else - and this is not the real problem?

Comment: Are you intentionally using a SecurityManager? Does the rest of the application work when a SecurityManager is in use? Typically, arranging for running an application under a SecurityManager requires quite a bit of care and feeding.

Comment: I really don’t know as we don’t run the tomcats . They are controlled by another department . If they are running a security manager would this be the result ?

Comment: You will only get these kinds of errors with a SecurityManager running. If your application hasn't been tested (and configured properly) to run under a SecurityManager, you are going to get *tons* of errors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The department hosting and managing our tomcat was running it with extra parameters which used a security manager.

They removed them and the problem went away.